# Make entire <div> inside <a> clickable

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm trying to make the entire content inside the `<a>` tag clickable but only the text is right now.

Here a CodePen: http://codepen.io/francobermudez/pen/dvBpNw?editors=1100

HTML:

```
<section id="ultimos-eventos">
    <div class="eventos-wrap">

        <a href="#">
            <div class="evento">
                <div class="evento-fecha">
                    <div class="evento-dia">20</div>
                    <div class="evento-mes">MAR</div>
                </div>
                <div class="evento-info">
                    <div class="evento-titulo">This is my title</div>
                    <div class="evento-subtitulo">
                        <div class="evento-direccion"><div></div>This is my subtitle</div>
                        <a class="btn-evento btn-azul" href="#">Detalles</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Put the anchor around the `div` you want as clickable

Comment: That's invalid HTML. An anchor element can't contain block-level elements like `<div>`. Why not just use JavaScript?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Well you know even in this page you can see `div` in anchors. think one day it'll stop working ?

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue Just because it works in most browsers doesn't make less invalid. And, because it is invalid, you don't know if a browser will revoke the code that makes it work, breaking your site.

Comment: Can't deny that, but as spread as it is, it'll never change. Whatever, since you have to learn how to do it, do it the right way. And don't put the anchor around block-level elements.

Comment: You cannot have <a> tag inside <a> tag, and for the top one, just remove anchor and add onclick attribute to div element. onclick="window.location.href='your-link'"

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan html5 allows blocks inside anchors - https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element, probable to stop the need for using js to make large areas clickable. But not nested anchors, that's just plain daft

Comment: Thanks everyone! @Imaginaroom I used your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: You CAN have <span> tags instead of <div> tags inside of <a>. Just sayin, it's a possibility if you really want that level of control inside of the anchor.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan What you are saying is only partially true. The content model of the <a> element is "transparent", which means an <a> can contain whatever elements its parent can contain. The only exception is interactive content (buttons, inputs, other a's etc), so the OP's <a> nested inside the <a> is bad. The <div>s are OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a link inside a link (The "Detalles" text) - that cannot work. Delete the inner link (i.e. convert it to a regular text div or p tag) and you'll be able to click the whole container.

```html
<section id="ultimos-eventos">
    <div class="eventos-wrap">

        <a href="#">
            <div class="evento">
                <div class="evento-fecha">
                    <div class="evento-dia">20</div>
                    <div class="evento-mes">MAR</div>
                </div>
                <div class="evento-info">
                    <div class="evento-titulo">This is my title</div>
                    <div class="evento-subtitulo">
                        <div class="evento-direccion"><div></div>This is my subtitle</div>
                        <div>Detalles</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
</section>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWbNjN?editors=1100